# How can I set fontSize in monaco editor?

Tags: css, font-size, monaco-editor

I want to set fontSize when I use Monaco Editor, But it's not work like this.

```
monaco.editor.create(this.$el as HTMLElement, Object.assign({
      language: 'sql',
      theme: 'vs-dark',
      fontSize: 20,
      folding: true,
      autoIndent: true,
      renderLineHighlight: 'line',
      scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
      wordWrap: 'on'
    }, this.options));
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't added the `px` after fontsize.

check below update code.

```
monaco.editor.create(this.$el as HTMLElement, Object.assign({
  language: 'sql',
  theme: 'vs-dark',
  fontSize: '20px',
  folding: true,
  autoIndent: true,
  renderLineHighlight: 'line',
  scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
  wordWrap: 'on'
}, this.options));
```

Also you can try some option on following link.

[Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-editor-editor-basic-options)